# Cocoa layout OSX (WebView - fill the space on the left + TextView - sidebar on the right with fixed width) how?

Tags: macos, cocoa, layout

i have spent hours and hours googling and trying to figure out how to make the layout work as described in the question.
I have put the WebView control inside the Window so it can fill the space, that is fairly easy and everything is working like a charm. On the right side, though, I would like to have a sidebar - which is basically a TextView with fixed with (I can toogle visibility of this).

Strange thing is, that if I put those Views next to each other (WebView on the left) and I am resizing the window, the web view is just keeping the size and TextView is being resized.
When I put the TextView on the left, again the TextView is being resized and the WebView is keeping the size, but I want TextView to keep its width and the WebView to resize.
Am I missing something? Probably yes..

Comment: yes, it is checked. if i uncheck it, it doesnt change the size at all in designer view, but in runtime after proper sizing settings for each view it works exactly how i wanted, thanks for pointing this out! ;)))

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to TheAmateurProgrammer, the issue was checked Auto-layout @ xib file.